# Relation to a table with a field of IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm completely new to `Asp.net Web Form`
I have a  method in my Repository which it returns `IQueryable`

```
 public IQueryable<Order> GetById(int CustId)
{
   return model.Orders.Where(e => e.CustId == CustId);

}
```

and the OutPut is like this:

[image]

I have a Relation from book table to order table. here is my model

[image]

and my question is this:

How I can Have a Repeater that it shows the information of the books which its BookId is in this `IQueryable` i mean `(Select * from books where id=bookId)`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you search is something like that:

```
public Book GetBookById(int bookId)
{
    return model.Book.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == bookId);
}
```

This methode returns you the information of a specific book.

Comment: But I want the information of all the books . and also i need to omit this grid view from the page . so how i can manage my object data source to bind to a repeater to show me the information of books ? what should i set for bookId?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want @nedaDerakhshesh. Do you want all book information for one Order?

Comment: Really Thank you for your care . It seems I should use join two table with linq to solve it.